# Show that $f(x)=\mu((A+x) \cap B)$ is continues, where $A,B \subset \Bbb R$ are measurable sets with a positive and finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A,B \subset \Bbb R$ be measurable sets with a positive and finite measure, and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure.
Define $f(x)=\mu((A+x) \cap B)$. Show that $f$ is continues.

I'm not sure how to approach this. Any clues?

Comment: Is $\mu$ Lebesgue measure? (The assertion will fail  if $\mu$ puts positive weight on certain singletons, or even if $\mu$ is not absolutely continuous.)

Comment: Thanks @JohnDawkins. Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Use that for every set of finite measure there exists a finite union of intervals that approximates the set.

Therefore, there exists $A_1$, $B_1$ finite unions of intervals so that 
$$\mu(A\Delta A_1) < \epsilon \\
\mu(B \Delta B_1) < \epsilon $$

Now, denote consider the function 
$$f_1(x)= \mu((A_1+ x) \cap B_1)$$

Show that:
$$|f_1(x)- f(x)| < 2 \epsilon $$
$$|f_1(x) - f_1(y)| \le m\, n|x-y|$$ if $A_1$ consists of $m$ intervals, and $B_1$ of $n$intervals  (this last one is a  poor estimate, but sufficient).

We conclude: if $|x-y| < \frac{\epsilon}{mn}$, then $|f(x) - f(y)|< 3 \epsilon$. Thus $f$ is (uniformly) continuous.